# How to fix the header and footer section in ios (ipad)?I am using jquery keyboard

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, header, footer

I have been trying to fix this issue since couple of days,Issue is my header and footer are coming to mid of the screen when i focus on the text field.I am not using the ipad keyboard instead of that i am using jquery keyboard for my application.

For now i have tried with this solutions:
1)

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input,tex', function () {
$('div[data-role="header"]').css('position', 'relative');
$('div[data-role="footer"]').css('position', 'relative');
$(document).scrollTop(document.body.scrollHeight);
$(document).trigger("refresh");
})
.on('blur', 'input,text', function () {
$('div[data-role="header"]').css('position', 'fixed');
$('div[data-role="footer"]').css('position', 'fixed');
});
```

2)

```
  $(document).on('blur', 'input, text', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft, document.body.scrollTop);
    }, 0);
    });
```

3)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write( '<style>#footer{visibility:hidden}@media(min-height:' + ($( window ).height() - 10) + 'px){#footer{visibility:visible}}</style>' );
    </script>
```

These solutions i have tried to reslove the issue but none of them worked fine.
please help me out with this issue.

Many Thanks in advance....